# CSV manipulation with shell script

Tags: linux, shell, csv, unix, data-manipulation

I have a CSV file like this

```
Country,Jan1,Feb1,.....,Dec16 
India,100,2000,........,1500
China,4768,46783,.......,3000
Canada,4789,7393,.......,9843
```

I would like to get the output with given below format

```
India,100,Jan1 
China,4768,Jan1
Canada,4789,Jan1
India,2000,Feb1
China,46783,Feb1
Canada,7393,Feb1
.
.
.
India,1500,Dec16
China,3000,Dec16
Canada,9843,Dec16
```

Could anyone please share, how the above things are possible in Shell script?

Thanks and Regards,
Robin David

Comment: Does it have to be a shell script? A Python script would be easier to write and almost as widely supported on linux?

Comment: Have you tried `awk` with `-F,`?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing code, any code. Just show us your best understanding solving problem. If you need a tutorial, start with http://grymoire.com/unix/Awk.html . Then with that info, post some code and people will help.  Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Rather than asking for humans to parse the example output and figure out what you want, try to carefully describe the output.  Then convert that description into a language that the computer understands.  And then you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this awk script:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN { ctrNo = 1 }

NR==1 { # store time colheaders
        for( c = 2 ; c <= NF; c++ ) TimeMember[ c-1] = $c;
        next
      }

      { # for NR > 1: store value under key country and TimeMember
        ctry = $1
        for( c = 2; c<= NF; c++ ) {
          key = sprintf("%s,%s", ctry, TimeMember[ c - 1 ] )
          values[ key ] = $c
        }

        if( !( ctry in seen) ) { 
          seen[ ctry ] = 1;
          countries [ ctrNo++ ] = ctry
        }
      }

END   {
        OFS=FS
        for( c = 1; c <= length( TimeMember ) ; c++ ){
          for( ctr = 1; ctr <= length( countries ) ; ctr++ ) {
            key = sprintf("%s,%s", countries[ ctr], TimeMember[ c ] )
            print countries[ ctr], values[ key ], TimeMember[ c ]
          }
        }
      }
```

You run it so: `awk -F, -f script.awk yourfile`

**Explanation**

- the `BEGIN` section initialises a variable
- the `NR==1` Action is executed for the first line, it stores all the TimeMembers from the first line. The `next` takes care that the other Actions are skipped.
- the following Action parses the data rows and stores the values from each TimeColumn with the CountryMember in `values`. Each new Country gets a new sequencenumber used during output in the `END` Action
- the `END` Action deals with printing the stored information. It loops over the different TimeMembers from the first line and over each member from the Country Dimension from the first column of the data lines.